# Truncated PHP-FPM / NGINX log lines

Tags: php, nginx, logging, fpm

I have a lot of lines in my PHP-FPM / NGINX logs that are truncated to 2048 bytes like this:

```
2022/05/15 16:06:16 [error] 899#899: *29892 FastCGI sent in stderr: "com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4121PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_title" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-qu
ery.php on line 4123PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_name" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4125PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/ultimateha
ckingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4121PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_title" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4123PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt 
to read property "post_name" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4125PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.
php on line 4121PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_title" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4123PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_name" on null in /var/www/ultima
tehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4125PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4121PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to r
ead property "post_title" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4123PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_name" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-qu
ery.php on line 4125PHP message: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/wordpress/wp-inclu
```

I've read many similar issues, and some people suggest recompiling NGINX, but I can't believe there's no other solution.

I've set the following options, which, to my knowledge, should solve the issue, but they don't:

- `log_errors_max_len = 8000` in `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini`.
- `log_limit = 8000` in `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`.
- `decorate_workers_output = no` in `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

Comment: I would suggest changing your logging settings so that PHP writes directly to a log file instead of having it bubble all the way through to nginx and having to worry about all the intervening layers. https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful and works as intended. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, then I'll mark it as the correct answer, and you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the logging settings in the config so that, instead of errors being printed to STDERR and percolating through the various intervening layers with their own constraints, the errors are written directly to a file by PHP.

The config directive is simply:

```
error_log = /path/to/file
```

**Ref:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Answer (score 0):

You can send error logs to stdout and log there with additional software.

**www.conf**

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /dev/stdout
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to configure this with PHP-FPM and NGINX?